Is there a way to choose which cell/column of a CSV to upload a dataframe into, just like scraping data onto an excel file?
I have had experience with webscraping data onto excel files, and I know that when copying data down into an excel spreadsheet, you can choose which column to copy it into. (startcol = 10 as shown in the snippet below)
with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
                    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="data", index=False, startcol=10)

However, when webcraping data onto a csv file, all my dataframes are going into the same column, making it an extremely long column. Is there a way to choose which column of a CSV file I can upload each dataframe to?
Here is the code I used for uploading data to my CSV.
df.to_csv('/Users/nicholaschan/Desktop/data.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)


Your terminology is confusing.  You're not uploading data, you're saving a dataframe to a file, in this case by appending lines at the end.  This will add more rows, it won't add more columns.  Highly abstracted functions like to_csv are convenient when they fit, but if you need specific behavior, then you need to format your dataframe the way you want, then save it.

If you read the documentation, you will see there is an option, columns=[]:
df.to_csv('/Users/nicholaschan/Desktop/data.csv', columns=['Name','Street','City'], mode='a', index=False, header=False)

Yo have to adjust columns names!
